# Changing Grid row color based on values in that row

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I have a grid with this columns : nrcrt, deadline, dateEnd, content.
The deadline and dateEnd column format are "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
I want to set Grid row color to red if deadline is greater than dateEnd and less than today.

```
thisform.grid1.SetAll("DynamicForeColor", "IIF(CTOD(SUBSTR(deadline , 1, 10)) >CTOD(SUBSTR(dateEnd , 1, 10)) and CTOD(SUBSTR(deadline , 1, 10)) <DATE() , 0, 255)")
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Your expressions didn't really make sense to me, you should revise what you need:

```
Create Cursor SampleData (Id i Autoinc, deadline c(20), dateEnd c(20))
Insert Into SampleData (deadline, dateEnd) Values ('2016/02/29 11:30:00','')

Insert Into SampleData (deadline, dateEnd) Values ('2016/02/01 12:00:00','2016/01/30 12:00:00')
Insert Into SampleData (deadline, dateEnd) Values ('2016/02/01 12:00:00','2016/02/01 12:00:00')
Insert Into SampleData (deadline, dateEnd) Values ('2016/02/01 12:00:00','2016/02/02 12:00:00')

Insert Into SampleData (deadline, dateEnd) Values ('2016/02/20 12:00:00','2016/02/19 12:00:00')
Insert Into SampleData (deadline, dateEnd) Values ('2016/02/20 12:00:00','2016/02/20 12:00:00')
Insert Into SampleData (deadline, dateEnd) Values ('2016/02/20 12:00:00','2016/02/21 12:00:00')

Insert Into SampleData (deadline, dateEnd) Values ('2016/03/01 12:00:00','2016/02/29 12:00:00')
Insert Into SampleData (deadline, dateEnd) Values ('2016/03/01 12:00:00','2016/03/01 12:00:00')
Insert Into SampleData (deadline, dateEnd) Values ('2016/03/01 12:00:00','2016/03/02 12:00:00')
Locate

Public oForm
oForm = Createobject('SampleForm')
oForm.Show()

Define Class SampleForm As Form
    Height=600
    Width=800
    Add Object myGrid As Grid With ;
        RecordSource='SampleData', Height=600, Width=800, Anchor = 15

    Procedure Init
        This.myGrid.SetAll('DynamicForeColor', '(thisform.GetMeColor())')
    Endproc

    Procedure GetMeColor
        Local deadline, dateEnd, lnColor
        deadline = Ttod(Ctot('^'+SampleData.deadline))
        dateEnd  = Ttod(Ctot('^'+SampleData.dateEnd))
        Do Case
            Case m.deadline > m.dateEnd And m.deadline < Date()
                lnColor=0
            Case m.dateEnd > Date() And m.dateEnd < Date()+7
                lnColor=Rgb(102,205,170)
            Otherwise
                lnColor=255
        EndCase
        Return m.lnColor
    Endproc
Enddefine
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the grid element you want to apply it to, for example Columns.

```
thisform.grid1.SetAll("DynamicForeColor", "Iif(Ttod(Ctot(Stuff(deadline, 11, 1, "T"))) > Ttod(Ctot(Stuff(dateend, 11, 1, "T"))) and Ttod(Ctot(Stuff(deadline, 11, 1, "T"))) <DATE(), 0, 255)", "Column")
```

If the 'deadline' and 'dateend' are character type in the table and of form "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" as you say then the Stuff() command will make that "yyyy-MM-dd**T**HH:mm:ss".

That form can then be converted to a date with Ttod().

It would probably be easier to add a computed column to the SELECT that the grid cursor is based on (you're not binding it directly to the table hopefully), i.e.

```
select ;
    deadline, dateend, blah, ;
    Iif(Ttod(Ctot(Stuff(deadline, 11, 1, "T"))) > Ttod(Ctot(Stuff(dateend,;
    11, 1, "T"))) and Ttod(Ctot(Stuff(deadline, 11, 1, "T"))) <DATE(), 0,;
    255) as forecolor ;
from mytable into cursor gridcursor
```

Then your grid ForeColor is just:

```
thisform.grid1.SetAll("DynamicForeColor", "forecolor", "Column")
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to prefix your datetime string values with a '^' and convert them with ttod(ctot()).

```
thisform.grid1.SetAll("DynamicForeColor", ;
"(IIF(ttod(ctot('^'+deadline))  > ttod(ctot('^' + dateEnd)) and ttod(ctot('^'+deadline)) < DATE(), 0, 255))")
```

You don't need to specify 3rd parameter, because DynamicForeColor can be applied to Column and derivatives only.

Comment: It works, but now I'm stuck with another problem, I want three color depending on my variables:  `thisform.grid1.SetAll("DynamicForeColor", ; "(IIF(ttod(ctot('^'+deadline))  > ttod(ctot('^' + dateEnd)) and ttod(ctot('^'+deadline)) < DATE(), 0, 255))" and "(IIF(ttod(ctot('^'+dateEnd))  >DATE() and ttod(ctot('^'+dateEnd)) < DATE()+7, RGB(102,205,170), 255))" `

Comment: You're getting up to unmanageable levels for a single expression. I would consider writing a function that takes the deadline and dateend dates and returns an rgb() value. Then in your SELECT for the grid cursor just have select deadline,dateend,x,y,z,getcolor(deadline,dateend) as mycolor

Comment: On forums like foxite, universalthread ... I always suggest to propagate complex expressions to a custom form method (or prg if you wish) and use a simple expression like: DynamicBackColor = "(thisform.GimmeColor(theControlSourceAndOrAnyOtherParameter))". I will create and send a sample for you as another answer.